# Same equation for a line and a plane in 3D?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can a equation $2y+x+z=3$ represent both a line and a plane in 3D?

The equation 
$$x = 1 + t$$
$$y = 2 - t$$
$$z = 0 + t$$
Obviously represents a line, and if use gaussian elimination I get:

$$2y + x + z = 3$$

which is obviously a plane. What happens here?

Comment: Remember _two_ planes define a line, just as two points define a line. In fact, points and planes are dual to each other in 3D. So a line and plane define the point through the plane, just as a line and point define a plane on the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: In your coordinate expression all coordinates are depending on $t$ (so you pick a value of $t$ which directly assigns values to $x,y,z$). In your last expression all variables are allowed to vary independently (e.g. you can set $y = 0$, $x = 0$ and $z = 3$, which was not possible in the previous expression).

In other words. Your system of equations has one degree of freedom $t$, hence it is a line. The second equation has two degrees of freedom, because as soon as you fix two of your parameters the last one is forced to have a specific value, hence it is a plane.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think I get it now. One last question if you don't mind: how can the expressions be equal if they do not represent the same thing? Gaussian elimination is obviously allowed and follows logically. How can I end up getting two expressions that are obviously not equal geometrically but equal logically?

Comment: @CuriousIdiot Without seeing the Gaussian elimination that you performed, it’s nigh impossible to answer you. Please show your work in your question.